# Data is not getting stored when filter is applied on Pig data

Tags: apache-pig

I am running in local mode.

```
pig -x local
```

This is my temp.txt

```
1925  44  999
1980  86  39
1928  60  42
1956  -10 54
1970  -5  55
1933  55  49
1977  44  59
1990  100 94 
1999  999 72
1989  77  81
1980  88  79
1990  98  77



Records1 = LOAD 'temp.txt' AS (year:chararray, temp:int, aqi:int);
```

I am able to load the data into records,but when i do filter i am able to read but storing is not happening..

Here is the command for filter:

```
Filtered = FILTER Records BY temp != 999 AND aqi !=999;
```

command to view contents of Filtered:

```
dump Filtered;
```

Here is the result of the above command..

```
Input(s):
Successfully read 12 records from: "file:///home/user/temp.txt"
Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "file:/tmp/temp-1913434963/tmp115707393"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0
```

Data is not getting stored ..could you please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code :

```
a = load '<path>/temp.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as (x,y,z);

b = filter a by y!=999 and z!=999;

dump b;
```

This will work properly.

Comment: Input(s):
Successfully read 12 records from: "/home/hduser/ex1.txt"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "file:/tmp/temp-1085097774/tmp-1342259884"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Comment: from by code . Dumping of b gives you the same result as above in your question

Comment: ok you can try to use 'illustrate' rather than dumping and find out what is the error in your code

Comment: because as per your question. I think my code will work fine because I run on my machine and it gives me the correct output.

Comment: So run your code line by line and illustrate it and find the error. If you cann't find the comment again. I will checked it once again

Comment: chown -R hduser:hadoop

Comment: Hi ,could you please tell me the meaning of this command : chown -R hduser:hadoop

Comment: chown -R hduser:hadoop .. This command is used for change the ownership. As the format of the command looks like ' chown owner-user:owner-group file  '. before : there is user and after : there is group name.

Comment: So here hduser is the owner-user and hadoop is the owner-group... For more go to http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchown.htm and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/

Comment: hi , I wanna analyse json data in pig ..here is my json data:[{"author":"gjkfhvk","title":"gdfjhsdgfjk","published":1997,
"reviews":[{"name":"fvdjk","stars":5},{"name":"dhjk","stars":4}]},
{"author":"ggkjhk","title":"gdfghfjhgh","published":1998,"reviews":[{"name":"jhjk","stars":6},{"name":"fghh","stars":6}]}]

Comment: here is my pig command:data = load '/home/user/Desktop/tej/pig.json' using JsonLoader('author:chararray,title:chararray,year:int,reviews:{review:(name:chararray,stars:int)}');

Comment: i getting output as :Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/user/Desktop/tej/pig.json"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp1826337556/tmp993730738"

could you please help me..

Comment: sorry i am getting output as:

Comment: Input(s): Successfully read 3 records from: "/home/user/Desktop/pig.json"

Output(s): Successfully stored 3 records in: "file:/tmp/temp1826337556/tmp244945211"

(,) (,) (gdfghfjhgh,{(jhjk),(fghh)})

not able to fetch the 1st array data that is title and reviews data ..

Could you please help me..

Comment: Okkk I will try to answer within an hour

Comment: problem was with my json..i removed the square brackets and put the data one line after the other..

Comment: I am Ankur Singh. and persuing my B.Tech from AKGEC,GZB and I am 3rd year student.

Comment: I work in the Big Data Center of Excellence. This is a lab in my college where only selected student work on the big data techology

Comment: Ok .. plzz help. emailId: ankur310794@gmail.com

Comment: Yes. I have learn Big Data from eduraka video and also teach the junior. But the main thing I have not done any certification course in Big Data

Comment: I have covered : - Introduction to Big Data , Hadoop installation , Basics Hadoop Ecosystem , Concepts of MapReduce , and Code in Apache pig and initial stage of Hive

Comment: Can you give me you email Id ?

Comment: i have a question related to pig can i ask

Comment: User information (id, email, language, location)
    Transaction information (transaction-id, product-id, user-id, purchase-amount, item-description)

Given these datasets, I want to find the number of unique locations in which each product has been sold.

Comment: I think you ask your question with some dummy data with input and output. Then I can help you

Comment: I can give you the logic

Comment: 1. Join the Frist and Second file by using the user_id

Comment: 2. Then group them by Product Id

Comment: 3. And then count district location and you will get the correct result

Comment: ya i got it..Thank you.

Comment: but what if i want to find no of same locations where the same product is being sold..

Comment: User_information

1,ab@gmail.com,english,bangalore
2,cd@gmail.com,kannada,bangalore
3,ef@gmail.com,hindi,andra
4,gh@gmail.com,telugu,mysore


Transaction information

1,2,2,200,pen
2,3,2,300,pen
3,4,1,400,scale
4,1,4,500,rubber

Comment: User_information 1,ab@gmail.com,english,bangalore 2,cd@gmail.com,kannada,bangalore 3,ef@gmail.com,hindi,andra 4,gh@gmail.com,telugu,mysore

Comment: User_information: 1,ab@gmail.com,english,bangalore 2,cd@gmail.com,kannada,bangalore 3,ef@gmail.com,hindi,andra 4,gh@gmail.com,telugu,mysore

Comment: Transaction information: 1,2,2,200,pen    2,3,2,300,pen     3,4,1,400,scale 4,1,4,500,rubber

Comment: Its simple yar. Again join and match them with location

Comment: how to generate all permutations of any given word  in mapreduce?

Comment: sorry , I have no knowledge about the coding in MapReduce. I have only knowledge about the concept of mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

[image: Input]

**Script**

```
A = LOAD 'test9.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (year:int,a:int,b:int);
B = FILTER A BY (a!=999 and b!=999);
DUMP B;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: Input(s): Successfully read 12 records from: "/home/hduser/ex1.txt" Output(s): Successfully stored 0 records in: "file:/tmp/temp-1085097774/tmp-1342259884" Counters: Total records written : 0 Total bytes written : 0 Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0 Total bags proactively spilled: 0 Total records proactively spilled: 0

Comment: hi, i have a question on dml mapping to pig transformation can i ask.

Comment: how to generate all permutations of any given word  in mapreduce?